# Finding pattern with sed, print lines until first empty line

Tags: search, sed, grep, find

I am trying to find a specific PID in a logcat and print all lines until the next empty line. The logcat looks something like this.

```
[ 07-17 11:15:14.003   483:  515 D/SensorService ]
Message

[ 07-17 11:15:15.300 20220:20225 D/dalvikvm ]
Message

[ 07-17 11:15:17.519   483:  515 D/SensorService ]
Message
```

What I have found searching for a solution to this problem is this:

```
sed -n '/pattern/,/^$/p' logcat
```

In this example I would like to do this

```
sed -n '/20220/,/^$/p' logcat
```

However, I cannot get this to work. It actually prints the entire logcat instead of filtering it. When I do execute

```
sed -n '/pattern/p' logcat
```

it works just as expected (like grep) but only taking the first line. In my understanding ^ represents the beginning of a line and $ the end, thus making ^$ an empty line.

I would be grateful for any inputs in how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Your `sed -n '/20220/,/^$/p' logcat` command should at least omit lines up to the first occurrence of 20220.  It ought to work correctly with the data, unless perhaps a Windows machine was used at some point and the `logcat` file has CRLF line endings and the `sed` doesn't treat the CR as part of the line ending.  (Downloading http://pastebin.com/6zDRbZu2 and then running `file logcat.txt` reports 'logcat.txt: ASCII C++ program text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators'.  The simplest fix is to convert the line endings to Unix style line endings, then run your `sed` command.)

Answer (score 6):

Through awk,

```
$ awk '/20220/{p=1}/^ *$/{p=0}p' file
[ 07-17 11:15:15.300 20220:20225 D/dalvikvm ]
Message
```

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n '/20220/,/^ *$/p' file
[ 07-17 11:15:15.300 20220:20225 D/dalvikvm ]
Message
```

But the above sed command prints also the blank line.

Comment: This does the exact same thing as my suggestion. It finds the first 20220, and then prints the rest of the logcat.

Comment: how?, woks for me. it finds the `20220` line and prints upto the next blank line. I think that's what you needed.

Comment: you are right, this seems to work, I tried a smaller part of my file and the behaviour is as expected. However, it does not work on my original .txt file with my logcat in it. Do you know what might be the cause to make sed not being able to do this in a file?

Comment: could you post the content of original logcat file in pastebin and then post back the link here.

Comment: @Oskar is there any line contains `20220`? What's your pattern? What's the number did i have to search for?

Comment: @Avinsha Raj here is the logcat pastebin.com/6zDRbZu2 . The PID number is irrelevant, it changes from time to time. I have tried mulitple of the PIDs. Take 461 for example.

Comment: yes i know. Like the above you gave the number `20220` likewise what's the number did i have to search for and print upto the next blank line.

Comment: 124 lines contain the number `461`. Did you want the all lines upto the corresponding next blank line?

Comment: @Avanish Raj 2984 or 461 would work fine. Yes, thats excatly what I would like.

Comment: awk command just works fine for me `awk '/461/{p=1}/^ *$/{p=0}p' file`

Comment: sed also works perfectly. Did you want the combined results of `2984` and `461`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this still does not work for me. I am on ubuntu 12.04, is it possible my sed and awk versions are outdated?

Comment: see the awk output of search pattern 461.But this is a part of my output http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn4sL.png

Comment: Okey. That looks good, and I would like to get that kind of output. But I am not able to mimic your result with the exact same execution.

Comment: just post your command in pastebin and post back the link here. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. It should works on 12.04 also.

Comment: Here is the link with my command and the last part of the output. http://pastebin.com/2vB8J74K

Comment: oH, it's strange. Did the logcat file located in the current directory itself?

Comment: Yes, the logcat file is in the current directory and sed -n '/461/p' logcat, for example gives the expected result

Comment: Could the file contain other space characters, such as `\t`? You may open a snippet of the file with `vim` and type `:set list` to check.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some other space characters in the file, such as `\t`.

Use `sed -n -r '/20220/,/^\s*$/p'` to have a try.